# Usb Debbuging is not working

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, windows, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-j1

I have Samsung Galaxy J1 4G, Android 4.4.4 KitKat and Windows 7. Previously I have installed [Intel App Preview](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intel.html5tools.apppreview), disabled and then enabled USB debugging and it works. Then, I uninstall and reinstall Intel App Preview and USB debugging is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem, I solved by remove and install samsung drivers from my computer.
In order to see if it is a 'driver problem' try to connect your phone in debug mode to another pc, better if it is running linux.